# Como faço para iniciar o Tomcat como serviço no Linux?

Tags: linux, tomcat

Preciso de colocar um sistema WEB em produção usando o **Tomcat 7**. Sei que posso iniciar com a shell `catalina.sh start` mas gostaria de algo que funcionasse após o reboot e que o Tomcat entrasse normalmente.

Answer (score 5):

Supondo o Tomcat7 instalado em `/usr/local/tomcat` você pode colocar a seguinte shell no diretório /etc/init.d

Você deve criar um usuário tomcat de forma que possa executar a shell dentro da sandbox dele.

**Arquivo:** tomcat7

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 345 98 99
# description: Tomcat auto start-stop script.
#
# Set OWNER to the user id of the owner of the Tomcat software.

OWNER=tomcat

case "$1" in
    'start')
        su - $OWNER -c "/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start >> /usr/local/tomcat/logs/tomcat7.log 2>&1"
        touch /var/lock/subsys/tomcat7
        ;;
    'stop')
        su - $OWNER -c "/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop  >> /usr/local/tomcat/logs/tomcat7.log 2>&1"
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/tomcat7
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Uso: $0 {start|stop}" 
        RETVAL=1
esac

# RESULT=`ps -ef | grep catalina | grep -v grep ` 
# echo $RESULT

exit $RETVAL
```

O nome de usuário `tomcat` não é obrigatório. Pode ser `tomcat7` por exemplo. O impotante é que o nome seja significativo na gestão de seus ativos de software.

**Instalando**

Para adicionar o shell script ao chkconfig faça:

```
cd /etc/init.d
chmod 755 tomcat7
update-rc.d tomcat7 defaults
```

Com o último comando, estamos dizendo ao sistema para inicie o script automaticamente no runlevel 3.

Mais detalhes do que seja um [RunLevel veja nesse link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Linux_Standard_Base_specification)

Para iniciar a execução do script sem um Rebbot faça:

```
service tomcat7 start
```

Para verificar se está rodando, pode checar através do `ps -ef | grep catalina`

**Conclusão**

O chkconfig cria links simbólicos apontando para o shell script em /etc/init.d dentro dos diretórios dos runlevel correspondentes : /etc/rc[0-6].d

Verifique o diretório:

```
ls -lA /etc/rc3.d
```

Observe que os links simbólicos ou começam com S (start) ou com K (kill) seguido de um número que representa a sua sequência de carregamento.

A sequência de carregamento é especificada na seguinte linha do script:

```
chkconfig: 345 98 99
```

Os números de inicialização/finalização podem ser os mesmos.

**Desinstalando**

Se precisar restaurar o sistema como estava antes disso tudo faça:

```
service tomcat7 stop
update-rc.d -f tomcat7 remove
rm -f /etc/init.d/tomcat7
```

Isso removerá o tratamento do chkconfig que você inseriu.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode executar esse script em `/etc/rc.local`.
Esse arquivo é executado logo após o boot.

O formato deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will “exit 0″ on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing

catalina.sh start

# Outro código ... etc...

exit 0;
```

---

Outra forma é criar um script em `/etc/init.d/tomcat7`.
Contendo:

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:        tomcat7
# Required-Start:  $network
# Required-Stop:   $network
# Default-Start:   2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:    0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start/Stop Tomcat server
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

start() {
 sh /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
}

stop() {
 sh /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/shutdown.sh
}

case $1 in
  start|stop) $1;;
  restart) stop; start;;
  *) echo "Run as $0 <start|stop|restart>"; exit 1;;
esac
```

Lembrando de dar as permissões ao script (como administrador):

```
chmod -x /etc/init.d/tomcat7
update-rc.d tomcat7 defaults
```

E, finalmente, você poderá iniciar o serviço:

```
service tomcat7 start
```

Comment: Você poderia também usar `sudo -u $OWNER "..."` para poder executar a operação com algum usuário definido como na outra resposta.

Answer (score 0):

> Segue o passo a passo para instalação do Tomcat 9 e Serviço no Linux, script atualizado está nesse [link](https://gist.github.com/jniltinho/a7bd30288342a5d352e6).

```
#!/bin/bash
### Install Tomcat 9 + JRE8 on Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS, OpenSUSE 64Bits
### URL com Screencast de Instalação do Tomcat9
### http://www.linuxpro.com.br/2017/04/instalando-tomcat-9-no-ubuntu/
### Link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7

## First install wget
## Primeiro instale o wget


# Check if user has root privileges
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
echo "You must run the script as root or using sudo"
   exit 1
fi


groupadd tomcat && useradd -M -s /bin/nologin -g tomcat -d /usr/local/tomcat tomcat

cd /usr/local/
wget --header 'Cookie: oraclelicense=a' http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jre-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar -xf jre-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz && rm -f jre-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz
mv jre1.8.0_131 java


echo 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH' >> /etc/profile

source /etc/profile
java -version


cd /usr/local/
wget http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/apache/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M19/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M19.tar.gz
tar -xvf apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M19.tar.gz
mv apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M19 tomcat
rm -f apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M19.tar.gz

cd /usr/local/tomcat
chgrp -R tomcat conf
chmod g+rwx conf
chmod g+r conf/*
chown -R tomcat webapps/ work/ temp/ logs/
chown -R tomcat:tomcat *
chown -R tomcat:tomcat /usr/local/tomcat



echo '# Systemd unit file for tomcat
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/usr/local/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/usr/local/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'
ExecStart=/usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target' > /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service


systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start tomcat
systemctl enable tomcat

## Open in web browser:
## http://server_IP_address:8080
```